# loop through fixed number of files within a directory

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, for-loop

How can I loop through a fixed number of files within a directory with `glob.glob`? If there's more than x files within that directory, I only want to loop through x and then exit the loop. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`glob.iglob()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to efficiently limit the number of results you can loop over:

```
from itertools import islice
import glob

x = 1000
limited_files = islice(glob.iglob('pattern.*'), x)
for filename in limited_files:
    #  handle filename
```

Even if there are many, way too many matches in a directory, you'll never handle more than the first 1000 matches, without creating several lists with matching filenames.